# Mono GC in Linux: why more memory occupied, more time to do GC and GetTotalMemory is so costly?

Tags: garbage-collection, mono

I have several game servers running on linux servers, and the initial memory size occupied by each server is different.

In each server, I write some performance logs to record the status of the server, for example, "how long one loop costs", "gc count during one loop". So when running idle, the memory size groups slowly due to the string allocation for the log, which leads to **0 generation GC**.

When I check the status logs after running hours, I find that each time GC happens, the loop time increases and I think that's reasonable. But what I don't understand is that the increasements of loop time due to GC are different, **the more memory occupied by the time GC happens, the more loop time increases**. As the log shows "600M memory usage takes only ***1ms*** to do one 0-generation GC but 2G memory usage takes ***15ms*** to do one 0-generation GC"!

As I know, Mono uses **Generational GC** with two generations Nursery and Major, so the 0 generation GC only needs to process the Nursery heap part(Write Barriers technique), and in my situation, the nursery part should be same size which contains the newly allocated string objects. Could anyone tell why?

In addition, when I use **GC.GetTotalMemory(false)** in mono to get how much memory the application uses, the loop time increases about 7-8ms every time. I've check the code of mono but still do not figure out why.

Comment: what version of Mono are you using? (is it the same version on all servers?) can you also test running with the `--server` flag?

Comment: mono version 5.12.0.226 and it's all the same on all servers, what's the difference with --server option?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the alive objects mark will cost more time. More objects alive in memory means larger tree the collector needs to search from roots.